# How to configure nuxt to bundle component into single js file?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, widget, vite

I have a standard [nuxt](https://nuxt.com/) application. This application includes some components that I would like to use not only within the app but also to package as a single JS file. This file could be then consumed by other webpages as a widget. Is there a way to have custom build configuration that I can use to bundle the component into, let's say `widget.js`?

Currently I am trying an approach where I decouple the widget app into its own package in the monorepo and use these components in the nuxt application using [defineNuxtModule](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/kit/modules#definenuxtmodule).

```
export default defineNuxtModule({
  setup(_, nuxt) {
    nuxt.hook('components:dirs', (dirs) => {
      dirs.push({
        path: path.join(__dirname, './src/components'),
        prefix: 'dt',
      });
    });
  },
});
```

In this package, which I set up as normal vue3 application, I am able to achieve this using following options in the `vite.config.ts`:

```js
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: () => 'widget.js',
        entryFileNames: () => 'widget.js',
      },
    },
  },
```

What would be the preferred way to achieve this? Thanks.